Current Arduino Stepper Control implementation in ROS
Working on my first ROS implementation but not new to robotics and machines.  I've been doing a lot of searches and using ChatGPT but I'm really lost on finding a current (and somewhat complete) Arduino->ROS implementation. Found a few rough templates but nothing specific.  Does anyone know of one or more current implementations?  I'm using Humble with an OPI4.
My plan was to adapt the Arduino software to run off an SKR2 or 3 Board along with 2208 drivers.  The hardware takes 12-24v and controls up to 5 axis on one board.  Thought a serial connection or CAN bus to it would be an easy implementation.
Should I bother to go down this path or am I better served just picking up one of the off the shelf stepper controllers.  Which is more expensive than my proposed approach.
Hoping there is a modern implementation of arduino and ROS that I'm just not finding. Thanks in advance!
